# Почему неправильно рассчитываются значения?

Tags: visual-c++, математика, c++-cli

Есть такой код

```
    public:
    int iter = 0;
    array<double>^ Xr;
    array<double>^ Yr;
    array<double>^ Zr;
array<double>^ res;

private: System::Void Button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    Xr = gcnew array<double>(100);
    Yr = gcnew array<double>(100);
    Zr = gcnew array<double>(100);
    res = gcnew array<double>(100);
    double x1 = 0;
    double x2 = 0;
    double x3 = 0;
    double eps = 0.0001;
    double tmpX = 0, tmpY = 0, tmpZ = 0;
    Xr[iter] = x1;
    Yr[iter] = x2;
    Zr[iter] = x3;
    iter++;
    while (true)
    {
        tmpX = x1;
        tmpY = x2;
        tmpZ = x3;

        x1 = X1Func(x1, x2, x3);
        x2 = X2Func(x1, x2, x3);
        x3 = X3Func(x1, x2, x3);

        Xr[iter] = x1;
        Yr[iter] = x2;
        Zr[iter] = x3;
        if ((Math::Abs((Math::Abs(Xr[iter]) - Math::Abs(Xr[iter-1]))) < eps) && (Math::Abs((Math::Abs(Yr[iter]) - Math::Abs(Yr[iter-1]))) < eps) && (Math::Abs((Math::Abs(Zr[iter]) - Math::Abs(Zr[iter-1]))) < eps))
        {break;}
        iter++;
        }
    label15->Text = Convert::ToString(x1);
    label10->Text = Convert::ToString(x2);
    label9->Text = Convert::ToString(x3);
    label12->Text = Convert::ToString(iter);
}
    private: System::Void Button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

        Form^ form2 = gcnew Form;
        form2->Activate();
        dataGridView1->Rows->Add(1, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i < iter; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1->Rows->Add(i+1,Xr[i], Yr[i],Zr[i], Math::Abs((Math::Abs(Xr[i]) - Math::Abs(Xr[i-1]))), Math::Abs((Math::Abs(Yr[i]) - Math::Abs(Yr[i-1]))), Math::Abs((Math::Abs(Zr[i]) - Math::Abs(Zr[i-1]))));
        }
        form2->Controls->Add(dataGridView1);
        dataGridView1->Visible = true;
        form2->Height = dataGridView1->Height;
        form2->Width = dataGridView1->Width+10; 
        form2->Show();
    }
```

По задумке,в результаты должно выводится |Xr[I]| - |Xr[I-1]|, но в последней строке откуда-то берутся неправильные значения. Я все проверил, несколько раз переписал код, что бы считалось по-разному, но все равно в конце всегда неправильное значение. Где я сделал ошибку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
    x1 = X1Func(x1, x2, x3);
    x2 = X2Func(x1, x2, x3);
    x3 = X3Func(x1, x2, x3);
```

не должны ли они от tmpX, tmpY, tmpZ вызываться?

Comment: Нет,   tmpX, tmpY, tmpZ я забыл удалить, они изначально использовались в if() вместо [iter-1], думал что это в них проблема и поменял. И в решении все верно, кроме проблемных ResultX1 и ResultX3 в последней строке

Comment: Там можно расширить столбец, посмотреть, что скрывается под многоточием? Нет ли там на конце "e-05".

Comment: Malcov   да, есть Е-05

Comment: Можно ли как-то избавится от E и привести значение к нормальному виду?